# Is there an easier way to show the selected item from SQL in the drop box using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap-4

I am trying to retrieve the country's name from the database and show the selected country, and I am using this approach, but using this approach will require me to do it for all 193 countries. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

```
<select name="nationality" class="form-control" id="nationality">
   <option value="Afganistan" 
      <?php if($row['nationality']=="Afganistan") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>
      >Afghanistan
   </option>
   <option value="Albania"
      <?php if($row['nationality']=="Albania") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>
      >Albania
   </option>
   <option value="Algeria"
      <?php if($row['nationality']=="Algeria") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>
      >Algeria
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Looks like you want a `for` loop

Comment: How do i implement that? Please suggest.

Comment: Why you not use `for` or `foreach` loop

Comment: Please show your query and array that you are getting from database.

Comment: Could you show a small example with my code, on how to implement it?

Comment: ```<?php
  if($r) {
   
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  ?> } }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to make dynamic select option like below.
I pick below array from https://gist.github.com/DHS/1340150

You can save this in your database and display

```
$countries = array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegowina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Indian Ocean Territory", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Congo, the Democratic Republic of the", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia (Hrvatska)", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "France Metropolitan", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia", "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard and Mc Donald Islands", "Holy See (Vatican City State)", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", "Korea, Republic of", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao, People's Democratic Republic", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia, Federated States of", "Moldova, Republic of", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Pitcairn", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia (Slovak Republic)", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St. Helena", "St. Pierre and Miquelon", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Taiwan, Province of China", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania, United Republic of", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands (British)", "Virgin Islands (U.S.)", "Wallis and Futuna Islands", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe");
```

```
<select name="nationality" class="form-control" id="nationality">
<?php foreach($countries as $key => $country) { ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $country; ?>" 
      <?php echo ($country == $row['nationality']) ? 'selected' :'' ?>
      ><?php echo $country; ?>
   </option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>
```